# Why its preferred to avoid Real domain (double/float) in condition statement ?

Tags: java, performance, types, dns, conditional-statements

For Example
If need to take action when `sqrt(x) = 10`
its preferred to avoid `Real domain` (double/float) in condition statement
And its recommended to use `Integer domain`

**The code**

```
int x = 100;

// Real (double/float) domain
if (Math.sqrt(x) == 10) { // Not recommended    
    // .... Action
}

// Integer domain
if (x == 10 * 10) { // recommended      
    // .... Action
}
```

Why i

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the floating point representation in memory uses [IEEE754](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) and this is not exact. This means that you could encounter cases where:

```
5.0 + 5.0 == 10.00000034634
```

instead of 10. And in IEEE754,

```
10 != 10.00000035246
```

Instead use a tolerance, using the absolute value of the difference:

```
if (Math.abs(Math.sqrt(100) - 10) < 0.00001)
{

}
```

Comment: @Martijn_Courteaux But how i encounter a case 
(5.0 + 5.0 == 10.00000034634) ??

Comment: try 64bit float: double a=1000000.00000000007; and see what is in a. Basically when you add/sub big and small abs values together then the precision goes away because the mantissa is small. Also all fractions which are not decomposable to power of 2 are truncated. Also Martijn Courteaux forget to add that FPU comparison is really slow because its done by either FPU via interrupts between CPU and FPU (crazy interface between them since 8088/8086 + 8087) or by software emulation which is more complicated then 1 or 2 CPU integer instruction done in few Tacts.